# SQL select from query returns incorrect information, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a application using codeigniter, this application has a profile page where all the information displayed is dependant on the user currently logged in. On the profile page I'm trying to set up a bio box so each user can write their own unique bio, this would be stored in the database. The code I've currently written is displaying a result on the page, but its not the correct result I was hoping for. The code I've written that relates to the problem is below.

In the model:

```
public function get_profile_information() { 

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT profileText from users WHERE 
    idNumber = ?", $this->session->userdata('username'));

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

In the controller:

```
public function loginprocess() { 

    $username = $this->input->post('idNumber');
    $password = $this->input->post('passWd');

    $query = $this->db->query("select * from users where idNumber='".$username."' and passWd='$password'");

    $row = $query->num_rows();

    if ($row) {

        $this->session->set_userdata(array('username' => $username));
        $sessionID = $this->session->userdata('username');

        $data['title'] = 'Profile';
        $data['profiletext'] = $this->news_model >get_profile_information();
        $data['sessionID'] = $this->session->userdata('username');

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/profile', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    } else { 

        $data['error'] = 'Invalid Login Details';
        $data['title'] = 'Login';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/login', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

In the view:

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

</head>

Welcome to the <?php echo $title; ?> page, <?php echo $sessionID; ?>

<?php var_dump($profiletext); ?>

<?php echo anchor('login/logout', 'logout'); ?>
```

On the webpage, the query to get the profile text from the database based on the logged in user gives this result

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["profileText"]=> string(17) "Test Profile Text" } }
```

I was hoping just to get the "Test Profile Text" displayed. I've been unable to work out what is wrong, I'm fairly new to codeigniter and php so I don't have the knowledge to fix this issue.

Comment: You should parameterize your second query as you did with your first. You should store your passwords as hashes, not plain text. `var_dump` is for debugging. You have an array use it as such, `echo $profiletext['profileText'];`

Comment: if you are serious about writing an application open to the public, with different users accessing different parts of your application/database:  please have a look at this: https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:
Make little change in below line

```
//$data['profiletext'] = $this->news_model >get_profile_information();//old line
$data['profiletext'] = $this->news_model->get_profile_information();//changes
```

Model:
To get only "Test Profile Text", without any change in your view

```
public function get_profile_information() { 

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT profileText from users WHERE idNumber = ".$this->session->userdata('username'));
    return $query->row('profileText');//changes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `echo` instead of [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

> Description:
>
> var_dump ( mixed $expression [, mixed $... ] ) : void This function
>   displays structured information about one or more expressions that
>   includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored
>   recursively with values indented to show structure.
>
> All public, private and protected properties of objects will be
>   returned in the output unless the object implements a __debugInfo()
>   method (implemented in PHP 5.6.0).

Replace

```
<?php var_dump($profiletext); ?>
```

By

```
<?php echo $profiletext[0]['profileText]; ?>
```

`echo` prints the variable(s) directly, as we require in our sites.